# "Connect to server" option changed in 14.04?? Can't connect using WebDav

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.  I would like to connect to my Android phone using WebDav.  I've done this from a Mac, from Windows, and from Kubuntu (using Dolphin -- this also works in Ubuntu using Dolphin) with no problem.  But when I select "Connect to server" I get this dialog box:

[New Dialog](http://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/directly-connect-to-windows-shared-folder-on-ubuntu.png)

But it used to look like this

[Old Dialog](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-QKjS5H_dqVI/TxWgEUL0XTI/AAAAAAAAClY/KpKWStH8op8/s1600/nautilus-connect-to-server-2.png)

Is there any way to get the old dialog back?  I would like to follow the tutorial under davDrive here (www.upubuntu.com/2012/01/some-free-apps-for-managing-your.html) (as it is intuitive and how Kubuntu worked), but I can't do it with the current dialog.

Is there any way to directly connect to a WebDav client inside Nautilus by typing webdav://10.0.1.15:8888/ into the location bar (CTRL-L)?  I get an error message every time: "Sorry, could not display all the contents of “10.0.1.15 (webdav)”: The specified location is not supported."  This too works in Dolphin.

Comment: Regarding the second question, the answer is to type "dav://10.0.1.15:8888/" into the location bar and/or the "Connect to Server" dialog box.  This is the prefix that Nautilus uses.  If someone knows of the list of prefixes, it would be helpful (for example, http does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the second question, the answer is to type "dav://10.0.1.15:8888/" into the location bar and/or the "Connect to Server" dialog box. This is the prefix that Nautilus uses

Answer (score -1):

Try using this one line format:

```
davs://<user_name>@<server>/<path>:<port>
```